# How to import a JSON5 file (as one can regular JSON) in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, json5

I would like to import a JSON5 file into a Javascript object in the same way [one can import a JSON file](import config from '../config.json').

[image: PrintScreen]

Shows this message on hovering but it's clearly there

```
Cannot find module '../conf/config.json5' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

I have 2 side questions related to the main one above:

1. Will I get intelisense for contents inside .json5, like regular json
2. Does it even work like it works with require()? Do I have to use import() instead of regular import ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need the package to do so: [json5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5).

There are one of two ways we can use this:

One: (target module system is CommonJS) require it

Following the README, we register json5:

```
import "json5/lib/register";
```

Then you can use `require` to import it:

```
const config = require("../config/config.json5");
```

Two: Reading the file and then using json5 to parse it:

```
import json5 from "json5";
import { readFile } from "fs/promises";

(async () => {
    const text = await fs.readFile("./path/to/config.json5"); // path to config.json5 from entry point

    const config = json5.parse(text);
})();
```

You can also use the provided CLI to convert json5 files to regular json that you can use.

Comment: Ah thanks, I thought I couldn't use require when specified to use imports in tsconfig

Also, I noticed I don't get intellisense with either of methods, any workaround on that?

Comment: If you mean `config` isn't the correct structure (probably `any`), you will have to explicitly type it yourself. However `json5` should have library typings provided already.

Comment: I tried for a while, doesn't look like I get autocomplete or any type checking on contents of that config.

Answer (score 0):

The creator updated the json5 wiki

[Wiki](https://github.com/json5/json5/wiki/Using-JSON5-with-TypeScript)

You need to create an extra file with `.d.ts` extension to support intellisense.